# CS Cart как отключать поля при оформлении заказа?

Tags: cs-cart

Всем привет! Подскажите, кто знает, как в CS Cart отключать/изменять/добавлять поля формы при оформлении заказа? Не смог найти в админ панели к сожалению! Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]